# Ajax request succeds but callback function never executes

Tags: php, ajax, extjs

The problem I face is that some of my ajax requests can be very heavy, in a sense that they do a lot of computation. In this case I can register in my server code the completion of the procedure (just by putting some debugging message into a text file), however in my client code I'm unable to execute a callback function. Example:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
      url:'computation.php', // it may take 5-10-20 or more seconds to complete
      loadMask:true,
      params:{...}, // some extra parameters
      method:'POST',
      success:function (result,request){
          alert("Done!!!"); // If the procedure takes too long, I do not see this echo
      }
});
```

I guess, the root of the problem may be in the result value, which I should return from the server side to the client. Probably, there should be some necessary arguments (like "success" : "true" - does I need it??) or something else.

Comment: It probably times out on the server side. What do you see in the console?

Comment: Sometimes I see "0" there. It looks like `http://localhost/computation.php    0` as if it times out. However, as I said, I still can register the completion of the procedure.

Comment: I guess I should tweak Apache configs somehow, but I do not know what exactly I should do to make my client side work.

Comment: Strange, you should add a `failure` callback to see if it goes there.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If a procedure takes too long, `failure` callback executes. But it is interesting why if I have `max_execution_time = 30000` in my `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 ways to know where is the problem :

1) Add a failure:function() in your extjs code :

```
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url:UrlOfThePhpFile,
            method:'POST',
            params:{yourParamName:yourParamContent},
            success:function(response){
               console.log("Ajax call is a success")
               debugger;
            },
            failure:function(response){
               console.log("Ajax call failed")
               debugger;
            }
        });
```

Open the development tools in Chrome and thanks to the "debugger;" you can examine the content of the var "response". It's like a breakpoint in your code.

2) There are an error log for apache. 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/

3) With an IDE like phpStorm, you can put some breakpoint in your php file and see if the file is called by the javascript

Comment: Well, at this moment apache log does not show me any error (I tried debug, notice and warn modes) even though I'm inside `failure` callback. I will check other options.

Comment: In Chrome I get `Failed to load response data`. However the procedure itself works fine and when it completes it writes for dubug puporses into a file.

Comment: Have you tried to bypassing your php code by writing > echo "OK" at the top of the php file?

Comment: Well, I;ve just done a simulation. I have this code for `computation.php` `<?php sleep(40); echo "1"; ?>`. And I have exactly the same problem. However if I run this procedure not from the ajax call, but right through the browser like `http://localhost/computation.php` I see a timeout for 40 seconds and then I see "1" echoed.

Comment: I've just even tested it with `curl` and got `HTTP 1.1 200 OK `. So, it is really Interesting why eventually get into `failure` callback.

Comment: Well, I found the solution. The problem was not in the server side, but in the client library `ExtJS` which, as it turned out, has default timeouts for requests.